# Crash on JellyBean

Tags: android, gridview

My app is currently having a FC when I'm using this code:

```
public class ArtistsFragment extends GridViewFragment{

public void setupFragmentData(){
    mAdapter = new ArtistAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.gridview_items, null,
                                    new String[] {}, new int[] {}, 0); 
    mProjection = new String []{
            BaseColumns._ID, ArtistColumns.ARTIST, ArtistColumns.NUMBER_OF_ALBUMS
    };
    mUri = Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    mSortOrder = Audio.Artists.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
    mFragmentGroupId = 1;
    mType = TYPE_ARTIST;
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't given enough information to get an answer. What is the exception? What line does it happen on? When are you calling setupFragmentData?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by rebuilding my project..

However, on my tablet where many images have to be loaded, I'm having an OutOfMemory so I'll have to work on this now..